# mount permission mechanism for file explorers

Tags: mount, sudo, nautilus

When I execute a script that uses the "mount" command, I need to enter my sudo password. However, I can launch a file explorer like nautilus and mount a filesystem from that application, without ever having to enter a password. What is the mechanism that allows some programs to execute commands that normally require root privilege?

My first instinct was that it is suid, but I changed the owner of a script to root and set the suid flag, i.e., "chmod 4777", but still I cannot perform things in the script that require root privilege.

Comment: @don-crissti: You should propose this either as a duplicate, or flesh it out as an answer, since no suitable answer was yet provided.

Comment: A suid script? See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html amongst others

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that suid shell scripts are always seen as a security risk, you need to specifc the `-p` shell flag to prevent the shell from restoring the uid to the real uid.

So you should add:

`#!/bin/sh -p`

to the beginning of your script